# How could you change colours of svg elements from an included file that is gotten using background-image: url("file-name.svg");

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Hi everyone I have a bunch of divs that has SVG images included as

```
background-image : url("svg-file-path.svg");
```

and sample SVG file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="30" viewBox="0 0 42 30">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g fill="#B4C9FF" stroke="#2C2C2C" stroke-width=".5">
            <path d="M954.263 146.25c-.368 3.826-.551 8.367-.551 13.625 0 5.292.186 10.585.558 15.879h0-41.004c.374-6.012.56-11.301.56-15.868 0-4.547-.184-9.092-.555-13.636h0z" transform="translate(-913 -146)"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I need to change the colour of the SVG images from javascript on some button click.

1. First how can I take the SVG object? 
   I tried to give ids to SVG files but that didn't work.
2. How can I change the colour of the SVG object

Comment: fill: currentColor?

Comment: a) have multiple files one with each colour you want or b) generate the background image as a data URL on the fly with javascript or c) alter the colours with a filter. The last is kind of hard to do if you only want to change 1 colour without affecting any other colours.

Comment: @AaronTomlinson yes fill current colour with a different one.

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah I thought using multiple files but wanted to know can I do it programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Apply a CSS filter that references an SVG filter with an feColorMatrix. Specify what color you want via the fifth column of the matrix. If you want rgb(50,10,180) for example, unitize those values by dividing by 255 (50/255, 10/255, 180/255) and you get the following filter:

CSS

```
.icon {
  filter: url(#recolorme); 
}
```

HTML

```
<svg height="0px" width="0px">
<defs>
  #ffff00
  <filter id="recolorme" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.196
                                         0 0 0 0 0.039
                                         0 0 0 0 0.706
                                         0 0 0 1 0"/>
  </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished entirely in css as well.

Add the rule
`filter: myStuffHere`
to the css class with the background-image.
You can choose any color with this [generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) here